# Is there a way to crop a NETCDF file?

Tags: linux, netcdf, nco, cdo-climate

Imagine that you have a file `example.nc`, that has wind data defined in 90N, 90S, 180E, 180W region. Is there anyway I could in linux, with a simple nc-type command (without extracting the data in matlab/python to rewrite), crop this file to include a smaller region, subset of the above.

For example, 30N, 10S, 60E and 30W.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`nco` works fine, but just to list an alternative, one can also do it using `cdo` (climate data operators), which I find easier to remember. You can specify directly the longitude and latitude values in this way:

```
cdo sellonlatbox,lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2 infile.nc outfile.nc
```

where lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2 define the boundaries of the area you require.

Note that longitude can be specified using 0:360 or also -180:180 conventions irrespective of that used in the input file. The output conventions will follow those used in the cdo command. This this command can also be used to convert a file from one format to the other.

For more details on extracting subregions, I have posted  [this video tutorial on youtube](https://youtu.be/ewii1p1kChw)

If you don't have `cdo` already installed you can get it on Ubuntu with

```
sudo apt-get install cdo
```

`cdo` has many other functions for processing, combining and splitting files and an excellent online documentation. Note that for `cdo` to work the coordinate variables (lat/lon) need to be defined according to CF conventions, so in that way the `nco` solution is more robust.

Comment: +1 for cdo. I've just been experimenting and it has a *lot* of useful features, I put up a couple of examples how to [crop by bbox, z axis, and temporal dimension here](https://medium.com/@danwild.io/crop-a-netcdf-file-by-xy-z-and-time-with-cdo-ee3f1e3a2678) (without needing to know index of course )

Answer (score 18):

Yes, using `ncks` from the `NCO` package: http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html

If you know the indices corresponding to the lat/lon range you want, let's say they are 30-40 in latitude and 25-50 for longitude for example, then you could crop the netCDF file with

```
ncks -d lat,30,40 -d lon,25,50 example.nc -O cropped_example.nc
```

make sure you specify the indices with integer values.

Otherwise you can also directly specify the range of the lat and lon values you want, but in this case you **must** make sure to use decimal points to pass the range as floats.

```
 ncks -d lat,30.,-10. -d lon,-30.,60. example.nc -O cropped_example.nc
```

Comment: Just as a heads up: Sometimes you might get an error unless you place a decimal after your dim ranges. So, if you have trouble, try: `ncks -d lat,30.,40. -d lon,25.,50. example.nc -O cropped_example.nc` instead.

Comment: @brews using a decimal indicates the range of actual lats/lons to extract over, while using integers indicates the range of _indices_ corresponding to the actual lats/lons.  Good to clarify!

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Linux or macOS, you can do this easily using nctoolkit (https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in python.

```
import nctoolkit as nc
data = nc.open_data("example.nc")
data.crop(lon = [25, 50], lat = [30, 40])
data.to_nc("output.nc")
```

Under the hood, `nctoolkit` uses CDO. So the above is the equivalent of the CDO approach mentioned above:

```
cdo sellonlatbox,lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2 infile.nc outfile.nc
```